# Do something if there are 8 children, if not do nothing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I currently have markup that looks like this -

```
<div class="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
  <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
  <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
  <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
  <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
  <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
  <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
  <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
  <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
  <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
  <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
  <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
  <div class="carousel-cell"></div>
</div>
```

And I'm trying to trigger a carousel plugin when there are more than 8 children called "carousel-cell" present and if there isn't then do nothing. Does somebody have a jquery call for this?

Comment: Use the `length` property: `if ($('.carousel .carousel-cell').length == 8)`

Comment: Are you asking if there is a trigger for each time an element is added, or how to count how many element there are?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check the length of jQuery object as shown below:

```
if($('.carousel .carousel-cell').length >= 8) {
    $('.carousel').yourPlugin();
}
```